# How to use octobercms with angular

Tags: angular, octobercms

My project is finished with angular6 and I want to add octobercms as backend.

My though is create api with octobercms and use angular to get api. Is it has a better way to do?

Comment: That sounds fine to me. What question do you have?

Comment: yes that is perfect !